# Got "The caller does not have permission [403]" when we call apps-script api

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-api

Hi every one I am working on google apps-script Api.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/script/v1.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';

class ApiTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ApiTestState createState() => _ApiTestState();
}

class _ApiTestState extends State<ApiTest> {
  var accountCredentials = new ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson({
"type": "service_account",
"project_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
"private_key_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"private_key":
    "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIExxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxDJlUBIRuMwo=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
"client_email": "xxxxxxx@yyyyyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
"client_id": "0000000000000",
"auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
"token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
"client_x509_cert_url":
    "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/xxxxxxx%40yyyyyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  });
  List<String> scopes = [
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.storage",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice"
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    main();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: Center(child: Text("Hello Worlds")),
  ),
);
  }

  void main() {
    clientViaServiceAccount(accountCredentials, scopes).then((http_client) {
      var service = new ScriptApi(http_client);
  ExecutionRequest request = new ExecutionRequest();
  request.function = "projectSummary";
  service.scripts.run(
      request, "1C9zxs82nICdyH_O8BMIU9vLpFLmDIZmzw5-3HVnJRvusrr8zMa8nIKXV");
});
  }
}
```

I have done.

1. **Deploy the script project as an API executable.**
2. **Provide a properly scoped OAuth token for the execution.**
3. **Ensure that the script and the calling application share a common Cloud Platform (GCP) 
   project.**
4. **Enable the Google Apps Script API**

**Scopes used in project**
[image]

I Got Response :- **status: 403, message: The caller does not have permission**

Please guide me why I got this error.

Comment: What are the sharing permissions of the script file? Also, who owns the script and whose credentials are you using in the OAuth process for your dart project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi everyone I got the solution.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart' as ga;
import 'package:googleapis/script/v1.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/io_client.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Google Drive',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Google Drive'),
    );
  }
}

class GoogleHttpClient extends IOClient {
  Map<String, String> _headers;

  GoogleHttpClient(this._headers) : super();

  @override
  Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(http.BaseRequest request) =>
      super.send(request..headers.addAll(_headers));

  @override
  Future<http.Response> head(Object url, {Map<String, String> headers}) =>
  super.head(url, headers: headers..addAll(_headers));
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata',
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.storage",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice"
  ]);
  GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount;
  ga.FileList list;
  var signedIn = false;

  Future<void> _loginWithGoogle() async {
    signedIn = await storage.read(key: "signedIn") == "true" ? true : false;
    googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged
        .listen((GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount) async {
      if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
        _afterGoogleLogin(googleSignInAccount);
      }
    });
    if (signedIn) {
      try {
        googleSignIn.signInSilently().whenComplete(() => () {});
      } catch (e) {
        storage.write(key: "signedIn", value: "false").then((value) {
          setState(() {
            signedIn = false;
          });
        });
      }
    } else {
      final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount =
          await googleSignIn.signIn();
      _afterGoogleLogin(googleSignInAccount);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _afterGoogleLogin(GoogleSignInAccount gSA) async {
    googleSignInAccount = gSA;
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
        await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
    );

    final AuthResult authResult = await                             
_auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;

assert(!user.isAnonymous);
assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

print('signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user');

storage.write(key: "signedIn", value: "true").then((value) {
  setState(() {
    signedIn = true;
  });
});
}

void _logoutFromGoogle() async {
    googleSignIn.signOut().then((value) {
      print("User Sign Out");
      storage.write(key: "signedIn", value: "false").then((value) {
        setState(() {
          signedIn = false;
        });
      });
    });
  }
  Future<void> _callApi() async {
    var client = GoogleHttpClient(await googleSignInAccount.authHeaders);

    var service = new ScriptApi(client);
    ExecutionRequest request = new ExecutionRequest();
    request.function = "functionName";
   var scriptId="1C9zxs82nICdyH_O8BMIU9vLpFLmDIZmzw5-3HVnJRvusrr8zMa8nIKXV";
    try {
      service.scripts.run(request,scriptId).then((op) {
    op.response.forEach((key, value) {
      print("key: $key");
      print("value: $value");
    });
  });
} catch (err) {
  print('error err');
  print(err);
}
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text(widget.title),
   ),
   body: Center(
     child: Column(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
       children: <Widget>[
         (signedIn
             ? FlatButton(
                 child: Text('Call Api'),
                 onPressed: _callApi,
                 color: Colors.green,
               )
             : Container()),
         (signedIn
             ? FlatButton(
                 child: Text('Google Logout'),
                 onPressed: _logoutFromGoogle,
                 color: Colors.green,
               )
             : FlatButton(
                 child: Text('Google Login'),
                 onPressed: _loginWithGoogle,
                 color: Colors.red,
              )),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the change you made for fixing it?